# Multiple like buttons issues creating the metas for facebook to read

Tags: php, facebook

I have added multiple like buttons to my page and then aim it to a static .php page for example:

Atricle.php (contains all my like buttons)
Facebook.php (is my dynamic page that creates the metas for the individual like pages)

So article 23 would be linked to facebook.php?art=23 this would then create the metas for this article.

However when I navigate to facebook.php?art=23 it loads fine with the correct metas but when I debug on Facebook it doesn't appear to read the php at all.

Is there a way round this/something I am doing wrong as I do not want to create 100's of pages just for static meta information.

Steve

Comment: Are you sure Facebook's crawler can rech that page and that you're not accidentally forgetting to include the `?art` param in your value for `og:url` on that page?

Comment: Definately there in the string og:url :-(

Answer (score 0):

When you plug one of your unique (http:// ... facebook.php?art=23) URLs into the [Facebook debugger](http://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug), it should show you the same Open Graph meta tags that correspond to that URL.

I can think of two reasons why this might not happen:

1) The Open Graph object for that URL has not yet been initialized because no action has triggered Facebook to crawl that URL yet.  (For example, the URL has not been Liked yet.)

**Solution:** Like the particular URL for the first time. (Also, be sure that the href parameter of your Like button exactly matches the "http:// ... facebook.php?art=23" URL that you are debugging.)

2) The debugger is showing cached, previous Meta content for that URL.

**Solution:** Refresh the cached meta content by using a fbrefresh parameter in the [Facebook debugger](http://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug).

**Example:** http:// ... /facebook.php?art=23&fbrefresh=AnyString

Note that the "?art" parameter does not need to be in the og:url for your article.  It does need to be in the href parameter of the Like button for your article.